# PHP Count the lenght of each value in a array/string (tags)

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Users writing an article have the option to write some tags, tags are written like this:

> tag1, tag2, tag3

So tags are stored like: `$tags = "tag1, tag2, tag3";`

I want to make sure, every tag has a minimum of 3 characters, so i need to validate the tags.

I have tried this:

```
$tagsstring = explode(",", $tags);

$tagslength = array_map('strlen', $tagsstring);

if (min($tagslength) < 3) {
echo "Error... Each tag has to be at least 3 characters.";
}
```

It seems to work, sometimes... But of you write:

> tag1, df

It wont give an error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$tagsstring = explode(",", $tags);

$trimmedtags = array_map('trim', $tagsstring);
$tagslength = array_map('strlen', $trimmedtags);

if (min($tagslength) < 3) {
echo "Error... Each tag has to be at least 3 characters.";
}
```

use this version it trims your strings before calcutlating the length.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that by exploding on a bare comma on input such as `tag1, df` you make the resulting array be `['tag1', ' df']` -- the second string actually has a length of 3.

The are two approaches to fix this that spring to mind:

1. Simply `array_map` with `trim` before calculating the lengths:

   ```
   $tagsstring = explode(",", $tags);
   $tagsstring = array_map('trim', $tagsstring);
   $tagsstring = array_map('strlen', $tagsstring);
   ```
2. Use a regular expression and [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to do the splitting:

   ```
   $tagsstring = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $tags);
   $tagsstring = array_map('strlen', $tagsstring);
   ```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hTALKL)**.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you said you want make sure `I want to make sure, every tag has a minimum of 3 characters`

if you are only worried about `alphabetical` charters then its a different game that means

`tab1` is valid

`tab200` is valid

`t299` not valid

`ta444` not valid

If this what you want then you can use this

```
$tags = "tag1, tag2, ta11  ,tag3 , df ";
$tags = explode ( ",", $tags );

function checker($tag) {
    preg_match_all ( '/[a-zA-Z]/u', $tag, $matches );

    return count ( $matches [0] );
}
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    if (checker ( $tag ) < 3) {
        echo "Error... Each tag ($tag) has to be at least 3 characters.\n";
    }
}
```

Output

```
Error... Each tag ( ta11  ) has to be at least 3 characters.
Error... Each tag ( df ) has to be at least 3 characters.
```

Comment: Thank you Baba, nice solution. Numeric characters is allowed though. But maybe it should not be, and then this solution is nice to have, thanks

Comment: +1 i like when people take their time to review and appreciate everyone who as made effort to help them ...